# Cython unable to import and execute a function: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I'm new to Cython and just trying to experiment with a simple script. I'm unable to import a function from a module and use it in another file, but if I declare the function in the same file it works just fine. What could be the problem here. Am I missing something?

This is the original code snippet (test_cy.pyx):

```
# test_cy.pyx

import json

cpdef char* say_hello():
  message = json.dumps({"message": "Hello world"})
  return message.encode()

cdef char* fn(int n):
  cdef char* hello = say_hello()
  return hello

def test():
  cdef char* n = fn(1000)
  print(n)
```

I can run it like (After compiling):

```
>>> import test_cy
>>> test_cy.test()
b'Hello world'
```

However, if I move the say_hello function to another file (utils.pyx):

```
# utils.pyx

import json

cpdef char* say_hello():
  message = json.dumps({"message": "Hello world"})
  return message.encode()
```

... And import it in my original test_cy.pyx file like so:

```
# test_cy.pyx

from utils import say_hello

cdef char* fn(int n):
  cdef char* hello = say_hello()
  return hello

def test():
  cdef char* n = fn(1000)
  print(n)
```

I'm unable to get it to compile as I get the following error:

```
>>> python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
...
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from utils import say_hello

cdef char* fn(int n):
  cdef char* hello = say_hello()
      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test_cy.pyx:4:7: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    sources=["utils.pyx"]
  File "/Users/asim/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1101, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/Users/asim/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1224, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: test_cy.pyx
```

Here's my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  ext_modules = cythonize([
    Extension("test_cy",
              sources=["test_cy.pyx"]
    ),
    Extension("utils",
              sources=["utils.pyx"]
    )
  ])
)
```

Please help me as something so simple like importing a function from another module shouldn't be  this complicated. I might be missing something trivial. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cpdef char* say_hello():
  message = json.dumps({"message": "Hello world"})
  return message.encode()
```

This is a disaster waiting to happen (although Cython doesn't seem to be able to generate a warning). The data that your `char*` points to is held by the result of `message.encode()` - a temporary Python object that is destroyed right after it's created. Therefore your `char*` is instantly invalid.

Think about this in C terms: to return a `char*` someone has to own the `char*` and you should know **exactly** who that owner is.
There isn't an easy, sensible way to returning a `char*` without taking responsibility for allocating/deallocating yourself. Unless you're prepared to do that and understand how to do that I suggest you delete all the `char*` from your code and just return Python objects.

---

The error you're getting is specifically because Cython uses `cimport` to know about Cython functions.

```
from utils cimport say_hello
```

Without `cimport` it believes that `say_hello` is just an ordinary Python function returning an ordinary Python object. However, even with this change your code is still invalid - you've just moved the error somewhere Cython can't see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I want to ask you something as I'm not too familiar with C. My functions are almost always going to be returning char* (bytes). Can you tell me what will be the proper way to do that? Just some resources will be great. Thanks again for the answer! :)

Comment: The trouble is that Cython doesn't (and can't) shield you from any of the complexity of C here. Therefore if you aren't familiar with C the best way is to return Python objects, not `char*`. If you _really_ want to use `char*` then you should allocate them with `malloc`, copy the data from the Python strings (probably `strcpy`) and free them with `free`, making sure that you `free` everything you `malloc` (and nothing more).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance! I will be looking into this in detail.